# StructureClone Function of pdf.js library is not working in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, pdf.js

StructureClone() is undefined! This is the error I am getting when I try to load pdf using pdf.js. It is working fine on all browsers except Firefox old version. I can't upgrade Firefox. So, Please suggest me an alternative of structureclone() function.